# Redeclaration in a namespace that does not enclose the original declaration

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer, definition, redeclaration

Namespace member can be defined in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s namespace:

> **Members of a named namespace can also be defined outside that namespace** by explicit qualification (3.4.3.2)
>   of the name being defined, provided that the entity being defined was already declared in the namespace
>   and the definition appears after the point of declaration **in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s
>   namespace**.

```
void f();

namespace N { void ::f() {} }       // illegal for definition

namespace N { void ::f(); }         // what about redeclaration?
```

Class can be defined in a namespace that encloses the declaration’s namespace:

> **If a class-head-name contains a nested-name-specifier, the class-specifier shall refer to a class that was
>   previously declared** directly in the class or namespace to which the nested-name-specifier refers, or in an
>   element of the inline namespace set (7.3.1) of that namespace (i.e., not merely inherited or introduced by
>   a using-declaration), **and the class-specifier shall appear in a namespace enclosing the previous declaration**.
>   In such cases, the nested-name-specifier of the class-head-name of the definition shall not begin with a
>   decltype-specifier.

```
struct A;

namespace N { struct ::A {}; }      // illegal for definition

namespace N { struct ::A; }         // what about redeclaration?
```

Also we have the same rule for member function definition and static data member definition.

So my question is whether redeclaration (not definition) is legal in a namespace that does not enclose the original declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning `struct ::A;`, [[dcl.type.elab]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.elab#1) makes your declaration ill-formed:

> If an *elaborated-type-specifier* is the sole constituent of a
>   declaration, **the declaration is ill-formed unless** it is an explicit
>   specialization (14.7.3), an explicit instantiation (14.7.2) or **it
>   has one of the following forms**:
>
> ***class-key attribute-specifier-seq<sub>opt</sub>
>    identifier* `;`**
>    `friend` *class-key*
>   `::`<sub>opt</sub> *identifier* `;`
>    `friend`
>   *class-key* `::`<sub>opt</sub> *simple-template-id* `;`
>    `friend` *class-key nested-name-specifier identifier*
>   `;`
>    `friend` *class-key nested-name-specifier*
>   `template`<sub>opt</sub> *simple-template-id* `;`

I don't see a problem in the function case; [[dcl.meaning]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.meaning#1) does permit it:

> When the
>   *declarator-id* is qualified, the declaration shall refer to a previously declared member of the class or namespace
>   to which the qualifier refers (or, in the case of a namespace, of an element of the inline namespace set of that namespace (7.3.1)) or to a specialization thereof; […]
>   [ *Note*: If the qualifier is the global `::` scope resolution operator, the *declarator-id* refers to a name declared
>   in the global namespace scope. — *end note* ]

However, both GCC and Clang insist that redeclarations, as definitions, must occur in an enclosing namespace.